# StartTime doesn't change in week , Month,Day view of FUllcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using the fullcalendar Ver 3.

the `minTime` is set to `"7:00"`.

```
  $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                locale: 'it',
                slotDuration: '00:15:00',
                minTime: '07:00:00',
                defaultView: 'agenda',
                defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
                contentHeight: 600,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: events,

               
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    selectedEvent = calEvent;
                    $('#myModal #eventTitle').html(calEvent.lastName + ' ' + calEvent.firstName + '<br>' + calEvent.phone);
                    var $description = $('<div/>');
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    if (calEvent.end != null) {
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                    $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                },
                selectable: true,

                select: function (start, end) {
                    $('#hdEventID').val(0);
                    $('#txtFirstName').val('');
                    $('#txtLastName').val('');
                    $("#txtCustomerId").val(0);
                    $("#txtPhone").val('');
                    selectedEvent = {
                        eventID: 0,
                        fullName: '',
                        lastName: '',
                        firstName: '',
                        description: '',
                        allDay: false,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        color: '',
                        Custd: 0
                    };                        
                    modaltest();
                    openAddEditForm();                                              
                },
                editable: true,
            });
        }
```

in the Month, Week, Day view when I want to enter a new event the time is set to 00:00

[image]

I changed the selectedEvent in select section to

```
start = start.add(moment.duration("07:00:00")).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A');
selectedEvent = {
      eventID: 0,
      fullName: '',
      lastName: '',
      firstName: '',
      description: '',
      allDay: false,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      color: '',
      Custd: 0
 };
```

But no success. why the 7:00 (minTime) wouldn't affect the form ( which is obviously the start value)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with minTime, that's just a visual thing - and it only applies to agenda views (not month or list or any others).

Comment: P.S. `defaultDate: new Date()` is not necessary - it's already the default setting to use today's date.

Comment: Anyway, in an agenda view, when you make a selection, the selected time will contain the selected date _and_ time already in the `start` parameter. So to put it into your textbox all you'd need to do is format it as whatever string format you need. Here's a demo - watch the Console when you make a selection and you'll see that the correct date is output successfully if you simply format the string: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGpQqpV?editable=true&editors=001

Answer (score -1):

You have to do appropriate changes in the Form>"BookingType.php" file.

Particularly in the $builder.

You may add for example:

'hours' => range(7,20), (to only be able to choose an hour between 7am and 8pm)